# AngulaJS using $rootScope in config phase for ngDialogProvider, or using ngDialogProvider in run phase

Tags: angularjs, ng-dialog

I know that you cannot inject $rootScope into the **config** phase of the application, AND I know that you can inject $rootScope in the **run** phase, but ngDialogProvider does not inject in the **run** phase...

I am using ngDialog and it has a ngDialogProvider where I can set the defaults of all my ngDailogs (I have lots)

I need to set a flag on the rootScope to prevent Navigation while the ngDailog is open.

How can I achieve this if we cannot inject rootScope in the config phase?

```
.config(['$rootScope','ngDialogProvider', function ($rootScope,ngDialogProvider) {
    // Inject Error: $rootScope cannot be injected here
    ngDialogProvider.setDefaults({
        onOpenCallback: function() {
            $rootScope.preventNavigation = true; 
        },
        preCloseCallback: function() {
            $rootScope.preventNavigation = false;
        }
    });
}])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do this in `.run`

```
.run(['$rootScope','ngDialogProvider', function ($rootScope,ngDialogProvider) {
    // Inject Error: $rootScope cannot be injected here
    ngDialogProvider.setDefaults({
        onOpenCallback: function() {
            $rootScope.preventNavigation = true; 
        },
        preCloseCallback: function() {
            $rootScope.preventNavigation = false;
        }
    });
}])
```

> ```
> ngDialogProvider is available in .config phase. Need to check if it is available on .run phase or not.
> ```

Edit 1: You can use global variable:

```
app.constant(‘preventNavigation’,false or true);

.config(['ngDialogProvider','preCloseCallback', function (ngDialogProvider,preCloseCallback) {
    ngDialogProvider.setDefaults({
        onOpenCallback: function() {
            preventNavigation = true; 
        },
        preCloseCallback: function() {
            preventNavigation = false;
        }
    });
}])
```

> constant should never be changed (though it is still possible to
>   change it programmatically in Angular 1.x).

Comment: Thanks for answer but I get an injector error on ngDialogProvider now

Comment: ngDialogProvider is available in .config phase. Need to check if it is available on .run phase or not.

Comment: Yeah it's not available during run phase

Comment: So if it is not available in the run phase is there no way to abstract the onOpenCallback and preCloseCallback functions where rootScope is available?

Comment: You can use  glob al variable. I am  updating my answer

Comment: thanks, isn't app.value('preventNavigation, false or true); the right way of defining the global? why use constant?

Comment: .value is not available during config phase.

Comment: Seem like the preCloseCallback works globally but not the onOpenCallback, I will have to open an issue with ngDialog

Comment: Mark accepted if it helped to get resolve the issue.